# text processing using python with given set of patterns

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

Having input.csv as following:

```
    field_name,field_friendly_name,include in report
    LastNm,Last_Name,
    cntn_last_mod_wrkr_full_nm,Last_Name,
    contact_last_nm,Last_Name,
    contact_first_last_nm,Last_Name,
    ,Last_Name,
    last_english_nm,Last_Name,
    ,,
    last_pronunciation_nm,Last_Name,
    ,Last_Name,
    last_nm,Last_Name,
    lead_space_last_nm,Last_Name,
    last_mod_usr_nm,Last_Name,
    lcl_last_nm,Last_Name,
    adobe_last_topic_nm,Last_Name,
    last_changed_user_nm,Last_Name,
    last_purchased_product_service_nm,Last_Name,
    last_imported_source_nm,Last_Name,
    submt_last_nm,Last_Name,
    cntct_last_nm,Last_Name,
    cust_submt_last_nm,Last_Name,
    cust_cntct_last_nm,Last_Name,
    last_mod_by_nm,Last_Name,
    last_mod_als_nm,Last_Name,
    last_mod_nm,Last_Name,
    ship_last_nm,Last_Name,
    billing_last_nm,Last_Name,
    last_upd_by_nm,Last_Name,
    wrkr_last_nm,Last_Name,
    trns_line_itm_last_chg_psn_nm,Last_Name,
    trns_line_itm_last_cre_psn_nm,Last_Name,
    trns_hdr_last_chg_psn_nm,Last_Name,
    altr_last_nm,Last_Name,
    trns_last_chg_nm,Last_Name,
    lastrepaction_nm,Last_Name,
    last_build_nm,Last_Name,
    LegalLastNm,Last_Name,
    ManagerLastNm,Last_Name,
    4-LastNm,Last_Name,
    NextLevelManagerLastNm,Last_Name,
    ManagerLegalLastNm,Last_Name,
```

Help needed is to write a code in python which will generate a csv file with desired output.

Conditions:

1. Read each line from input.csv file. (first row is column name).
2. Condition: If column1 value is only made of given set of words (in this case last, name, nm, lst, -, _, [0-9] ) update column2 & column3 as found & true respectively. And search should be case insensitive
3. If condition fails update column2 & column3 as not_found & false, respectively.
4. Also remove entire row if column1 is blank.

My desired output should be as below:

```
    field_name,field_friendly_name,include in report
    LastNm,found,TRUE
    cntn_last_mod_wrkr_full_nm,not_found,FALSE
    contact_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    contact_first_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_english_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_pronunciation_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_nm,found,TRUE
    lead_space_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_mod_usr_nm,not_found,FALSE
    lcl_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    adobe_last_topic_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_changed_user_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_purchased_product_service_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_imported_source_nm,not_found,FALSE
    submt_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    cntct_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    cust_submt_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    cust_cntct_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_mod_by_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_mod_als_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_mod_nm,not_found,FALSE
    ship_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    billing_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_upd_by_nm,not_found,FALSE
    wrkr_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    trns_line_itm_last_chg_psn_nm,not_found,FALSE
    trns_line_itm_last_cre_psn_nm,not_found,FALSE
    trns_hdr_last_chg_psn_nm,not_found,FALSE
    altr_last_nm,not_found,FALSE
    trns_last_chg_nm,not_found,FALSE
    lastrepaction_nm,not_found,FALSE
    last_build_nm,not_found,FALSE
    LegalLastNm,not_found,FALSE
    ManagerLastNm,not_found,FALSE
    4-LastNm,found,TRUE
    NextLevelManagerLastNm,not_found,FALSE
    ManagerLegalLastNm,not_found,FALSE
```

FYI, in desired output following are the only column1 values that matches the criteria.

```
LastNm,found,TRUE
last_nm,found,TRUE
4-LastNm,found,TRUE
```

I could do part of this using awk in Unix, need help to do the same work in python, what commands or packages needed to do this and what could be simplest code that we can do this with python.

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, 'gensub(/last|lst|name|nm|[0-9_-]*/,"","g",tolower($1))=="" {
    $2="found";
    print $1, $2
}' file
```

with this code I'm getting an output like-

```
LastNm,Found
last_nm,Found
4-LastNm,Found
```

Comment: Could you please make more clear what you want to do? Some bullet points or a list would be helpful

Comment: @Dash, sure let me be very clear, I will update question

Comment: Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service. We can help solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to help us help you.

Comment: @Dash I've edited the question, please review and let me know if that is understandable.

Comment: @MisterMiyag I've tried with Unix awk command but requirement is to do on pythong so I'm not sure what packages to use and commands to use. if someone can guide me that would be of great help.

Comment: Each of the tasks you are trying to do maps directly to Python functionality. Do you know how to read CSVs? Do you know how to make conditionals? Do you know how to compare case-insensitive? Do you know how to read and set "column values" (sequence elements)? Do you know how to skip elements during iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a pretty broad question, here's some hints in the right direction.

You're dealing with a csv file, so I would recommend looking at [python's `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). It has an example for reading and writing to a file. You will also need the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), specifically `re.compile()` and `re.match`.

From there, I would make a list that holds each modified, and write it to a file with `csv.writelines()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different problems here. First is the processing of a csv file: the `csv` module will do it perfectly. Second is to test whether a name is only composed from case insensitive elements of a set. Here I would use a regex with the `re` module.

Code could be:

```
rx = re.compile(r'(last)|(name)|(nm)|(lst)|([-_0-9]+)', re.I)

with open('input.csv') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w',  newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    wr.writerow(next(rd)) # copy header line
    for row in rd:
        txt = row[0].strip()  # ignore leading or ending blank characters
        if txt != '':         # reject lines with an empty first field
            if '' == rx.sub('', txt):     # only elements from the set
                wr.writerow((txt, 'found', 'TRUE'))
            else:
                wr.writerow((txt, 'not_found', 'FALSE'))
```

---

```
import re
import csv

rx = re.compile(r'(last)|(name)|(nm)|(lst)|([-_0-9]+)', re.I)
with open('C:\temp\input.csv') as fd, open('C:\temp\output.csv', 'w',  newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    wr.writerow(next(rd)) # copy header line
    for row in rd:
        txt = row[0].strip()  # ignore leading or ending blank characters
        if txt != '':         # reject lines with an empty first field
            if '' == rx.sub('', txt):     # only elements from the set
                wr.writerow((txt, 'found', 'TRUE'))
            else:
                wr.writerow((txt, 'not_found', 'FALSE'))
```

Error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1a294c9517ff> in <module>()
      3 
      4 rx = re.compile(r'(last)|(name)|(nm)|(lst)|([-_0-9]+)', re.I)
----> 5 with open('C:\temp\input.csv') as fd, open('C:\temp\output.csv', 'w',  newline='') as fdout:
      6     rd = csv.reader(fd)
      7     wr = csv.writer(fdout)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\temp\\input.csv'
```

Comment: is rx.sub supposed to be re.sub ?

Comment: and also can you please let me know where to place keywords - last, name, nm, lst, -, _, [0-9]

Comment: @Achar007: looks like I had forgotten one line :-( . Post edited now.

Comment: is throwing an error can you look at code and output added in your asnwer.

Comment: @Achar007: Beware `\ `  is special in a Python string! You must either have it quote itself (`c:\\temp\\input.csv`) or use a *raw* string (`r'c:\temp\input.csv'`).